# Return an object in VBA

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll

I've built a custom DLL which, for this example, has a function `login`. In C++ I use it by creating an object and then accessing the function through the object pointer, like so:

```
ConnectMe *cm = new ConnectMe("216.239.51.99");
cm->login("username", "password")
```

What I'd like to be able to do is use this code in Excel. I've created a DLL and have exported the appropriate functions. How can I do this in VBA? Does VBA support returning pointers to my own custom objects? This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx) fails to specify what kinds of types can be returned from a function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your DLL is registered in machine, in tools/reference, set the check to.

After, in your code use

```
dim cm as new ConnectMe

cm.ConnectMe("216.239.51.99")

cm.login("username","password")
```

Comment: When declaring the function above would it similar to this: Declare Function ConnectMe Lib "cm.dll" (ByVal Arg1 As String) As ConnectMe